# ajax POST not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

posting data from field inputs to a php page.

on test of one or two this works fine but when using all this doesn't work.

i am trying to get the value of each of the fields and then use them variables posted to the php.

```
$(function(){
    $('.gobtn').click(function(){

        userKey = 'abcdefghijklmnop' ;
        alias = $("input[userprofile='alias']").val();
        about_me = $("input[userprofile='about_me']").val();
        other_names = $("input[userprofile='other_names']").val();
        location = $("input[userprofile='location']").val();
        website = $("input[userprofile='website']").val();
        email = $("input[userprofile='email']").val();
        contact_num = $("input[userprofile='contact_number']").val();
        facebook_link = $("input[userprofile='facebook_link']").val();
        twitter_link = $("input[userprofile='twitter_link']").val();
        pinterest_link = $("input[userprofile='pinterest_link']").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                userKey : userKey,
                alias : alias,
                about_me : about_me,
                other_names : other_names,
                location : location, 
                website : website,
                email : email,
                contact_num : contact_num,
                facebook_link : facebook_link,
                twitter_link : twitter_link,
                pinterest_link : pinterest_link
                },
            url: 'script_a.php',
        //    dataType: 'json',
        //    async: false,

            success: function(result){
               alert('success'+result);
            },

            error: function(){
               alert('error');
            }
          });
    });
});
</script>
```

**The Html**

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" >Alias</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alias" userprofile='alias' aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['alias']; ?>' />
 </div>

 <br />

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">About me</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="About me" userprofile='about_me' aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['about_me']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

 <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Other names</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Other names / aliases" userprofile='other_names' aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['other_names']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Location</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Location" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" userprofile='location'  value='<? echo $row['location']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Website</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" userprofile='website' value='<? echo $row['website']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Public Email</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Public Email - Can be seen in your profile publicly" userprofile='email' aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['email']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Contact Number</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" userprofile='contact_number' value='<? echo $row['contact_number']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Facebook</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alias" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['facebook_link']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Twitter</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alias" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['twitter_link']; ?>' />
 </div>

  <br />

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Pinterest</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alias" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2" value='<? echo $row['pinterest_link']; ?>' />
 </div>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to make up your own attributes on elements. You should use `data-userprofile` rather than `userprofile`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it works with one or two, but not all? One or two of what?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error in the Javascript console? What do you see in the Network tab, is it sending the parameters to the server? What is the server response?

Comment: Can you add the HTML that goes with this? Do you have multiple forms? If so, you need to get the values of the inputs in the current form, your code will get them all from the first form on the page. You need to use `var form = $(this).closest("form");` and then use `form.find("input[userprofile=alias]")` to get that input field.

Comment: i found the problem. Using 'location' as a variable was resetting the window location and then breaking the ajax.

Comment: Right. You should declare local variables with `var location`, then they won't conflict.